# How to safely raise server room humidity

Tags: server-room, physical-environment

We've just completed an office move and had no time after the construction of the office to run any sort of environment testing on the new server room. The server room is a good size and the temperature is okay but my issue is that the air is too dry. The air is just under 25% RH and I would like to see that number in the 40's if possible.

The caveat is that we were under the impression that the server room would get it's own AC unit in the new room, which isn't the case. The cooling of the room is currently dependent on the entire office cooling (not my idea). With that said the cooling might hamper my efforts to get the humidity up a bit.

Does anybody have any good recommendations of quick, effective but most importantly *safe* measures I can put in place to raise the humidity in my room?

Comment: just drink lots of water

Comment: Wouldn't the rest of the office be at 25% RH since the a/c sends air to the office too? I'd look at a humidifier for the a/c if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Humidity is controlled usually with steam, infrared (that creates steam), Ultrasonic (that generates a dry saturated vapor, or evaporative that uses a wet medium.  You could contact something like the AmeriVap system, but then heat is an issue.

You could always go with a cool mist humidifier. But you will have to keep an eye on water levels.

Really the best idea is to just bring in a steam generating canister, low cost and be prepared to keep constant contact with that machine.  Check levels every day.